# Blob and Hero animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, blob, flutter-animation

Is there any way to animate the blobs using Hero widget in flutter? When I'm trying to do that, it is not animating perfectly.
This is my code :

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          await Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageRouteBuilder(
                  reverseTransitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => TechnologyAnimation()));
        },
        child: Hero(
            tag: 'technology-animation',
            child: Container(
              child: Blob.animatedFromID(
                loop: true,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
                size: 300,
                styles: BlobStyles(color: Colors.red),
                id: ['5-5-6092'],
              ),
            )),
      )
```

It will navigate to another page and there is another blob of a different size.